# Get AD Group membership changes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to **monitor** our important **group membership changes** in Active Directory (e.g Domain Admin changes) to see if someone has been added to the group or removed.

Has anybody a powershell script or something else for this? Right now I'm sending myself an automated email every friday with the members in it but not the changes. This is done with PS. But can it be done in the MS Security center as well and how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to configure [the appropriate audit policy settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-group-membership) in the Default Domain Controllers policy for the domain, at which point the DC's will automatically start logging changes to group memberships in the `Security` event log channel - you can then frward these events to a central store or set up event log triggers to email you.

Comment: Thanks Mathias - I will try that out!